# How would I take user input and add it into an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I have currently written a class called PostTUI and I need to know if I could take the input people write from my scanner and add it into my arraylist.

```
public class PostTUI {

    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private PostManager manager;
    private String userChoice;
    private String author;
    private String message;

    public PostTUI(PostManager manager) {
        this.manager = new PostManager();
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1 - Create a new Message Post");
        System.out.println("2 - Create a new Photo Post");
        System.out.println("3 - Create a new Event Post");
        this.userChoice = this.scan.nextLine();

        if (this.userChoice.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Who is the author?");
            this.author = this.scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the message?");
            this.message = scan.nextLine();
            this.manager.addPost(Post newPost);
        }

    }
}
```

The PostManager class is the class who's job it is to declare and initialize the arraylist. It has a method that accepts and stores a post (addPost) and a toString method.

Comment: The last line of code there is not working so I'll just assume I did something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made it explicitly clear where you use an `ArrayList`, but presumably inside the `PostManager` and you add to it with the `add()` method. In any case, that's not how you create a new object, which is why the last line is giving you an error message. You want this instead:

```
this.manager.addPost(new Post());
```

You haven't shown us the `Post` class, but maybe you want to pass the author and message `String`s as arguments to the `Post` constructor?

Comment: I have inheritance for each of the message, photo, and event posts classes that inherit from post. All I need to do is What you said except change Post() to this.manager.addPost(new MessagePost(author, message)); and it worked. Thanks man!